# Discrete RV problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

A flight control system uses four independent computers working in parallel. At each critical step, the computers “vote” to determine the appropriate step. The probability that a computer will ask for a roll to the left when a roll to the right is appropriate is 0.0001. Let X denote the number of computers that vote for a left roll when a right roll is appropriate. What are the mean and variance of X?

Please help. So far I've taken a RV with a range (0,1,2,3,4) I'm having trouble visualising how to get 5 probablities for the range that add up to 1, given that our given probability is 0.0001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $X$ has the binomial distribution